# Regex pattern matching incorrectly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a regex pattern that is trying to match a string, but it's doing it incorrectly so I'm going to point out parts of the regex pattern and what it does in hopes of getting it right this time:

```
~  : the start of the regex pattern
,  : trying to match the , at the start of the string
.* : 0 or more of any characters in between
=? : stop at the first match of the rest of the pattern
\. : a period
\" : a quote
/  : a slash
>  : arrow right
<  : arrow left
~  : end of pattern
```

**Code:**

```
$content = ", not good in any manner or degree. See more.\"/><"

$regex = "~,.*=?\.\"/><~"; 
preg_match_all("/$regex/siU", $content, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Error:**

```
Unknown modifier '/'
Unknown modifier '>'
Unknown modifier '<'
```

But as far as I know only these  [\^$.|?*+(){} are regex meta characters that needs to be escaped. Anyway, I escaped the / and the <, and the error went away but this time I got an empty array instead.

```
$regex = "~,.*=?\.\"\/\>\<~"; 
preg_match_all("/$regex/siU", $content, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

**Results:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "**Regex pattern matching incorrectly**" The regex is right you're wrong.

Comment: You must be using a regex to parse HTML, right? If yes, that is the culprit.

Comment: @PedroLobito What are you saying? I'm getting an empty array. How is that correct?

Comment: @stribizhev What do I do?

Comment: I'm just saying that your title is wrong, the regex is always right,  you're wrong because you didn't code it properly.

Comment: What are you attempting to capture in your string?

Comment: @PedroLobito *facepalm. Seriously? I thought you were pointing out something relevant.

Comment: @LeoCHan I'm trying to capture the sentence of the string.

Comment: @frosty "**Regex pattern matching incorrectly**" Wrong title, the regex is matching **correctly**.

Comment: @LeoCHan Which is this "not good in any manner or degree. See more"

Comment: @PedroLobito Are we seriously having a debate on what titles should be call? Do you, or do you not have anything relevant to the code above to say?

Comment: @LeoCHan Yes. That is sufficient.

Comment: Why are you assigning a pattern to a variable, and then doing `"/$regex/siU"`? why don't you just write `preg_match_all("/~,.*=?\.\"/><~/siU", $content, $matches);`? Because all escaped chars in the `$regex` variable need to be escaped twice

Comment: @frosty I may have a solution, but I would like to know first if your intent is to parse text from html. Is this your intention?

Comment: @LeoCHan Yes. That is my intention.

Comment: @frosty: Don't: markup and regex don't mix. Markup needs to be _parsed_, not consumed by regex's ([the `DOMDocument`class](http://php.net/DOMDocument) is worth a look)

Comment: What are you trying to capture ? Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Comment: @frosty Ok, this may not be the answer you are seeking (a regex), but I think it will help you much more since it's not really wise to parse html with regex. If you want to parse the text out of html in php, I would recommend something like [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for parsing html in php.

Comment: @LeoCHan Can you write me an example using phpQuery for the above question?

Comment: @frosty I believe you would do something like `$text = pq('all the html')->find('selector for myelem')->text();`. Sorry, it's been a while since I've done some php.

Comment: `phpQuery` last update was 4 years ago... you should use the buildin php class `DOMDocument` http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php  examples http://www.binarytides.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape all your backslashes and also you are using two delimiters `~` and `/`, you can use below code:

```
$regex = "~,.*=?\\.\"/><~siU"; 
preg_match_all("$regex", $content, $matches);
```

You can quickly see this using any regex online tool like regex101

https://regex101.com/r/dT1pQ7/1

Btw, not sure if you wanted to make your `=` optional or not but `=?` makes `=` to be optional.

Update: after reading your comment to "stop" at the first match you have to use a non greedy operator by adding `?` after the quantifier as [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85) said makes the trick, so `.+?` or `.*?` are lazy or nongreedy quantifiers making to stop at the first occurrence

Comment: Escape all the backslashes except for the one with the quote?

Comment: Also, I thought =? means stop at the first \\.\"/><.

Comment: `.*?` means stop at the first. `=?` means the `=` is optional.

Comment: Just tried, $regLinks = "~1\\..+?\\.~siU"; and it didn't stop at the first period.  Btw, I'm using this in html.

Comment: @jessica, cannot help you without an example. Can you post a regex101 link with your sample?

Comment: @frosty Can you put a sample data and your expected output?

Comment: @Fede I finally figured out what I did wrong. It was probably luck, but I got what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @frosty glad you figured it out. Hope I helped